# After IPN is received update order column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am integrating Paypal IPN into my marketplace app. I have been wrestling with the MVC architecture trying to get this to work.

I want to update a :purchased_at column in the order's database after receiving the IPN response of "VERIFIED". Then the Order model will use a callback to save the order after the create action is the :purchased_at column is not nil.

The idea is really to use the IPN response to save an order to the database but I can't figure out how to make the controllers/models communicate properly.

## PaymentNotificationsController

```
class PaymentNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:create] #Otherwise the request from PayPal wouldn't make it to the controller
  def create
    response = validate_IPN_notification(request.raw_post)
    case response
    when "VERIFIED"
      order.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now)
    when "INVALID"
    else
    end
    render :nothing => true
  end

  protected
  def validate_IPN_notification(raw)
    uri = URI.parse('https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.open_timeout = 60
    http.read_timeout = 60
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    http.use_ssl = true
    response = http.post(uri.request_uri, raw,
                         'Content-Length' => "#{raw.size}",
                         'User-Agent' => "My custom user agent"
                       ).body
  end

end
```

## PaymentNotification.rb

```
class PaymentNotification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end
```

## Order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"
  after_create :purchased?

    private

    def purchased?
      if :purchased_at != nil
        order.save
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: your question is not specific, also line `:purchased_at != nil` doesn't make sense, `:purchased_at` is just a symbol, you probably want remove `:`

Comment: @JoeHalfFace The order.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now) will not work because its being accessed from a different controller. The error from the server is this NameError (undefined local variable or method `order' for #<PaymentNotificationsController:0x007fac8a8bfe78>):

app/controllers/payment_notifications_controller.rb:7:in `create'